# iText nested tables last row expanding

Tags: itext

I am doing this, to have table 1 and table 2 side by side.

```
masterTable.addCell(table1);
masterTable.addCell(table2);
```

But here is the problem. If one of the tables has more rows than the other table. The table with less rows will grow the last row to get to same height as the other.

How to avoid this?

Comment: That's the expected behavior and will work the same way if you're dealing with plain text. Lokks like you want to place two indepent tables side by side instead of nested tables.

Comment: How can I place 2 tables side by side without using nested tables?

Comment: Place the tables at absolute positions with `PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows()`. I still don't understand your constraints. If you want two columns side by side use `ColumnText` and add the table to it. You'll have to explain better the why, I'm out of guesses.